# Adding column in Views for completed submission plus several days

Tags: views

A have a table column using Views from Webform submission. The variable of this column is submission date [completed].

I need to create another column showing another date [completed] + 7 days.

I tried Global: Math expression
[completed]+7
but it does show the correct date but another value.

How can I display [completed]+7 in another column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my own problem. Using [Views PhP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module.
Add field Global:PHP,
in the output code box:

```
<?php
$correctdate = $row->completed; 
$correctdate1 =strtotime("+7 days", $correctdate);
$cdate = date("j/n/Y - g:i a", $correctdate1);
echo ($cdate);
?>
```